# Excel PivotTable; how to show values horizontally

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to rearrange a pivot table that organizes all values (not sum or other statistic) from an original table.  Seems simple but I can't find a way to make it values rather than sums.

My original data looks like:

```
Rank    Name
1       A
1       B
2       C
2       D
3       E
3       F
```

and with the pivot table I get something like:

```
Rank  Name
1       A
        B
2       C
        D
3       E
        F
```

and I would like to rearrange it like so:

```
1          2            3
A          C            E
B          D            F
```

Comment: This is not possible with a Pivot Table. Pivot Tables show a value for the relationship between Column and Row header. There is no relationship between `2` and `B`, and if there were the value would not be `D`. You will probably need a VBA routine to pull this off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a way to achieve that using array functions instead of pivot tables.
Suppose your original data is located in A1:B7.
To get the headers row (1, 2, 3):

```
A10: =MIN(A2:A7)
B10: =SMALL($A$2:$A$7,COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,"<="&A10)+1)
```

Then copy B10 as far right as you need to get all other values

To get the values for each rank, set an array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) on the range A11:A16 (or lower to fit more items) with this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$7,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$7=A$10,ROW($A$2:$A$7)-ROW($A$2)+1),ROW()-ROW(A$10))),"")
```

Then copy this range (A11:A16) as far right as you need...

Comment: Whoa, pretty slick. That array solution worked perfectly. Thanks!